# Maria DB - Execute a stored procedure for each row in a SQL event

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Hi I am wanting to make a SQL event, which applies a stored procedure to each row, any example?

```
    SELECT
  u.cod_emp,
  u.usu_login,
  u.usu_est,
  s.ses_acc,
  MAX(s.ses_date) AS ses_date
FROM
  usuario AS u
  JOIN SESSION AS s
    ON s.cod_emp = u.cod_emp
WHERE u.usu_est = 'I' AND
s.ses_date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
GROUP BY u.cod_emp
ORDER BY u.cod_emp ASC
```

can I execute for each row a store procedure?, As?

I'm using MariaDB

Comment: The other way around: execute 1 stored proc that executes the above query, then loops through the results and does something with each record.

Comment: *which applies a stored procedure to each row, any example?* See [Cursors](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/programmatic-compound-statements-cursors/)

Comment: This appears to return non-determinate results for s.ses_acc

Comment: Would a `TRIGGER` work for you?